# IntelliJs code-completion doesn't show parameters names

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-completion

I recently made a switch from Netbeans 7 to IntelliJ 13 and so far I'm very happy. However in Netbeans I found the code-completion to be a bit better, despite reading nothing but praise for IntelliJs code-completion.

My code-completion in IntelliJ just shows parameter types, not names. I have attached picture to show you.
[image: Netbeans, IntelliJ]

As you can see, Netbeans show the entire function declaration, which is useful if you don't know every method by heart or just forgot if "is name or address first?".

Is there a way to make IntelliJ behave the same way?

//EDIT: I use Windows 7, my IntelliJ is community version 13.0, build #IC-133.193

Comment: I have a default install of IDEA and mine does this. Where did you get your version from and are you sure it's version 13? Which OS?

Comment: If you write the function it will show what you want if I don't remember wrong. Anyway try to search in intellj idea help it's big

Comment: @Xabster I added some info to OP

Answer (score 0):

Configure the SDK properly.

Ctrl+alt+shift+s -> SDKs -> Click the + and find your SDK

Comment: In particular, JDK sources should be attached, otherwise there's no way for IDEA to figure out the parameter names.